# How to create function that takes a text string and returns a dictionary containing how many times some defined characters occur even if not present?

Tags: python

Hello I asked this question previously and I wanted to adjust the code that I have now. I want to adjust this code so that if a letter is not present in a text string it still returns the value 0 to it assigned.

```
    count = {}
    for l in text.lower():
        if l in let:
            if l in count.keys():
                count[l] += 1
            else:
                count[l] = 1
    return count
```

It currently returns this:

```
example = "Sample String"
print(func(example, "sao")
{'s': 2, 'a' : 1}
```

This would be my desired output

```
example = "Sample String"
print(func(example, "sao"))
{'s': 2, 'a' : 1, 'o' :0}
```

Comment: This is not related to pandas or seaborn. Removed the tags

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using tools designed especially for your purpose, then the following will do:

```
from collections import Counter
def myfunc(inp, vals):
    c = Counter(inp)
    ​return {e: c[e] for e in vals}
s = 'Sample String'
print(myfunc(s, 'sao')
```

Otherwise you can explicitly set all missing values in your functions.

```
def func(inp, vals):
    count = {e:0 for e in vals}
    for s in inp:
        if s in count:
            count[s] += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# create a function
def stringFunc(string, letters):
    # convert string of letters to a list of letters
    letter_list = list(letters)
    # dictionary comprehension to count the number of times a letter is in the string
    d = {letter: string.lower().count(letter) for letter in letter_list}
    return d

stringFunc('Hello World', 'lohdx')


# {'l': 3, 'o': 2, 'h': 1, 'd': 1, 'x': 0}
```

Comment: Why converting to list and calling .lower() every time instead of setting string=string.lower() at the beginning?

Comment: @SUTerliakov I find it better to work with lists than strings as a general rule. This is just a quick example. If I was actually going to write the code for practical use I would 1. not use a string for a list of letters. 2. I would lower the list of letters as well and not just the string . 3. Use type hints, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Dict Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) and [str.count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

```
def count_letters(text, letters):
    lower_text = text.lower()
    return {c: lower_text.count(c) for c in letters}

print(count_letters("Sample String", "sao"))

result: {'s': 2, 'a': 1, 'o': 0}
```

Comment: Note that compexity here is O(nm), where n and m are lengths of input strings. It's much more than approx. O(n) with dict updating in a loop (because finding element in dict is O(1) in general if hash collisions are rare among keys, which is true for 'a'-'z' chars).

Comment: Yes. That's a very good observation and is important to know it especially if `text` or `letters` are long strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and obtain character counts via the `get` method:

```py
from collections import Counter

def func(string, chars):
    counts = Counter(string.lower())
    return {c: counts.get(c, 0) for c in chars}
```